# How to control the docker swarm dns resolver

Tags: dns, docker-swarm

I've created a swarm service called "dnsforwarder" which controls the dns queries and I need to force the client services from an overlay network to use it.

In such case the clients `/etc/resolv.conf` are forced to contact the swarm internal resolver/forwarder with `nameserver 127.0.0.11` (see [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/#dns-services)). I could create these client services with the `--dns` option so as to specify the forwarder to use but it's only accepting an IP address, which I can't guess because dnsforwarder is a swarm service. And I can't force its IP because it is not supported by swarm (see [here](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24170)) ...

So I don't see how I could configure my clients to contact my dns forwarder service..  The only solution I can imagine could be to force `/etc/resolv.conf` with a docker config like that :

```
    nameserver dnsforwarder
    nameserver 127.0.0.11
```

That doesn't look great... and I would need some suggestions or advices

Thank you